# Display different text depending on a word in url

Tags: php, html, web

I have a header that basically says something like this:

"
**Forum**

A great place for support.
"

And I need it to display on certain pages of my site, the ones related to the forum.

However on other pages I might want a header like:

"
**Donate**

Help keep us online.
"

The adresses on the forum part of the site would be similar to these.

```
http://localhost/index.php?p=/discussions
http://localhost/index.php?p=/activity
http://localhost/index.php?p=/discussion/6/oh-dear#Item_1
```

And the donate one might be like this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?p=/plugin/page/donate
```

So I need some way to have a script that goes

```
if url has (discussions, activity, discussion)
then use this header
"<b>Forum<b> <br> a great place for support

if else url has (donate)
then use this header
"<b>Donate<b> <br> help keep us online

else
use this header
"<b>Website<b> <br> this is our website
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Javascript `location` object:

```
url = location.href;
if (url.indexOf('discussions') && url.indexOf('activity') && url.indexOf('discussion')) {
  document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(child-element);
else if (url.indexOf('donate')) {
  document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(other-child-element);
}
else {
 document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(another-child-element);
}
```

Comment: I don't think JavaScript should be used for this task

Comment: It shouldn't be, or it can't be? If he wants to some DOM manipulation based on user-action, he will have to take recourse to JS. Of course, you can work around it, you can have PHP store the URL in a JS variable and send it on page-load. That variable can be used by other functions later.

Comment: Should not, I'd say. An URL is no user action :-)

Comment: I didn't mean user-action on the URL, I meant that perhaps he needs to alert some part of the URL when the user interacts with the **`DOM`**.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For that interaction one could/should use JS. However, the OP asked for outputting different html snippets based on the URL

Comment: Yes, if he wants to output the snippets from the server while sending the page itself, then obviously PHP is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A function like this might help. 
And if you don't know how to get variable from url, use $_GET['p']

```
function contains($substring, $string) {
    $pos = strpos($string, $substring);

    if($pos === false) {
            // string needle NOT found in haystack
            return false;
    }
    else {
            // string needle found in haystack
            return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You just rewrote the `strpos()` function, but switched the parameters. How does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do this serverside, you could always use PHP's [`strpos()` function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) It will return the location of a string within another.  So all you would have to do is examine the [`$_SERVER['query_string']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable and execute an `strpos()` search -

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'forum')) >= 0){
  // forum appears in the query string!
}
```

The `strpos()` function returns the index of the string you are searching, so remember that **`0` is a valid index**.  When `strpos()` does not find a match. it will return `false`.

Here what I'm doing is examining one of the [`$_SERVER` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), they contain all sorts of information about the server and what it's current parameters are.  One of these is the query string - that's all the text that comes after the `?` in the URL.  Once I have that, the `strpos()` function will search for something in that value.

Comment: Is the OP trying to do it from within PHP?

Comment: @cup - good question! We can't exactly determine that from the post.  A JS solution has already been given, so this is the serverside alternative :)

Comment: Could you explain this one a little more, im somewhat new to this. This is how I interpret using it,                                  <? 
   if (strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],'discussions')) >= 0) {
   $headcode = "<h1>Forum</h1> <p class="lead">A great place for support</p>"
   }
 
   ?>
 
   <?echo($headcode)?>

Comment: I recommend you consider my other answer actually... I'll add some more explanation to this one...

Answer (score 0):

Another (more elegant) serverside solution for you... If your URL's are always appearing with the "path" in the `p` parameter, you could utilize PHP's `explode()` and `in_array()` functions to make your code a little more easy to handle.  Take this URL for example -

```
http://localhost/index.php?p=/plugin/page/donate
```

If we execute an `explode()` function on the `$_GET['p']` variable, we'll get an array like this -

```
Array(
  'plugin',
  'page',
  'donate'
)
```

Now you can execute an `in_array()` function to see if the string you are looking for exists in this array -

```
if (in_array('form',explode($_GET['p']){
  // we are in the forum!
}
```

References -

- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: This does look like the best solution, I still dont fully see how to use it though, how do I define the different things it should look for  to give a true value?